# Reset handle after ReadFile

Tags: c++, winapi, readfile

I'm trying to open a file on windows and check that the magic bytes match a windows PE32. If I run the code below and return just before the `ReadFile` call in the function `problemFunction` the code works fine and it prints `5a4d` at the end of the main function. However if I return after the `ReadFile` call in `problemFunction` then I exit in the `dos->e_magic != PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` check.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

void problemFunction(HANDLE *fh) {
    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(fh, NULL);
    if (!fileSize) { CloseHandle(fh); exit(1); }

    BYTE* pByte = new BYTE[fileSize];
    DWORD dw;
    ReadFile(*fh, pByte, fileSize, &dw, NULL);
    // could be wrong but i think i need to run SetFilePointer here but not sure on what to do.
    return;
}

int main() {
    const char* filepath = "C:\\windows\\file\\path\\to\\exe";
    HANDLE fh = CreateFileA(filepath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { CloseHandle(fh); exit(1); }

    problemFunction(&fh);

    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(fh, NULL);
    if (!fileSize) { CloseHandle(fh); exit(1); }

    BYTE* pByte = new BYTE[fileSize];
    DWORD dw;
    ReadFile(fh, pByte, fileSize, &dw, NULL);

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)pByte;

    if (dos->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) { CloseHandle(fh); exit(1); }
    // dos->e_magic should be 5a4d for MZ, windows PE
}
```

I assume i need to reset the file pointer after the `problemFunction` read call with something like

```
LONG reset = -sizeof(DWORD);
SetFilePointer(*fh, reset, NULL, FILE_END);
```

But i can't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: FILE_END seeks relative to the end of the file, you want to either seek back from the current position (FILE_CURRENT) or just seek to the start (FILE_BEGIN with an offset of 0).

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks the FILE_BEGIN with offset 0 worked

Comment: There are some holes in your explanation. **First:** _" If I [do a certain thing] the code works fine"_ -- so isn't that your solution? The code works fine. Problem solved! *(If you meant that a certain* part *of your code works fine, please be more precise.)* **Second:** Your example code never calls `problemFunction`, so I don't see how anything in `problemFunction` could affect your results.

Comment: @JaMiT obviously the call to `test()` in `main()` was meant to be calling  `problemFunction()` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I assume something is "obvious", I end up being wrong at least 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

`problemFunction()` is taking a `HANDLE*` pointer as input, but it is not dereferencing that pointer when passing it to `GetFileSize()` or `CloseHandle()`. But it is dereferencing the pointer when passing it to `ReadFile()`.

You must be compiling your code with [STRICT Type Checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/strict-type-checking) turned off, otherwise your code would fail to compile. You should always compile with STRICT enabled.

`HANDLE` is a pointer type, so there is no need to pass it around by pointer, unless you are going to modify its value, which this code is not doing. So you should change `problemFunction()` to take a `HANDLE` as-is rather than taking a `HANDLE*` pointer.

Also, `GetFileSize()` does not return 0 on failure, like your code assumes. It actually returns `INVALID_FILE_SIZE` which is -1, ie `0XFFFFFFFF` as a `DWORD`. This is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesize):

> If the function fails and lpFileSizeHigh is NULL, the return value is INVALID_FILE_SIZE. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

But, most importantly, your 2nd call to `ReadFile()` inside of `main()` does not read what you are expecting because the 1st call to `ReadFile()` inside of `problemFunction()` has already read the data (and leaked it!), but you are not seeking the `HANDLE` back to the beginning of the file after that read so the 2nd call to `ReadFile()` can read it again. You are correct that you need to use `SetFilePointer()` for that.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

bool test(HANDLE fh) {
    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(fh, NULL);
    if (fileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE) {
        return false;
    }

    BYTE* pByte = new BYTE[fileSize];
    DWORD dw;
    if (!ReadFile(fh, pByte, fileSize, &dw, NULL)) {
        delete[] pByte;
        return false;
    }

    // use pByte as needed...

    delete[] pByte;

    if (SetFilePointer(fh, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    const char* filepath = "C:\\windows\\file\\path\\to\\exe";
    HANDLE fh = CreateFileA(filepath, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (!test(fh)) {
        CloseHandle(fh);
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(fh, NULL);
    if (fileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE) {
        CloseHandle(fh);
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE* pByte = new BYTE[fileSize];
    DWORD dw;
    if (!ReadFile(fh, pByte, fileSize, &dw, NULL) || dw < sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)) {
        CloseHandle(fh);
        return 1;
    }

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)pByte;

    if (dos->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) {
        delete[] pByte;
        CloseHandle(fh);
        return 1;
    }

    ...

    delete[] pByte;
    CloseHandle(fh);

    return 0;
}
```